# when creating a new C++ console app VC++ gives C libs?

Tags: c++, c, dependencies, external

I recently tried making app windows using C in VC++ 2010.

I changed some additional dependency settings for my project. But after doing this, every time I create a new C++ project VC++ gives me what is to be believed C external dependency lib files despite giving cCand C++ extern dependency libs.

What have I done and how do I fix it? As its starting to do my head in to be honest.

Comment: What does the error look like?

Comment: Before it would give me libs like: cerrno, cfloat, climits, cmaths, etc all the libs it would normally give you. After it started giving me the likes of crtdefs.h, mbstring.h, sal.h etc which I'm guessing are C only libs? Other than that there are no errors

Comment: Those are headers, not libraries, and they can certainly be used from C++ programs.  What do you mean that "it is giving [you]" those?  _Where_ is it "giving" you those?  How are you creating your new project?  What is the file extension of your source file?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, and when you create a bew project you are given three folders named 'External Dependencies' where the header/ source files are stored for things like iostream, fstream, string etc. Then there is the 'Header' folder where as the name states, custom made header files are stored. And finally the 'Source' folder where the main and custom source files are then stored. Originally when I created a new .cpp console app I had about twenty header/source files in the external dependencies folder , now I get about ten with files like stdio etc

Comment: Hans Passant - No I'm not having problems with Intellisense

Comment: The "External Dependencies" folder just lists all of the headers that the C++ IntelliSense engine has discovered are in use by your project.  If you include, for example, `<vector>` in one of your project's source files, then right click the project and select 'Rescan Solution', `<vector>` (and its dependencies) should show up in External Dependencies.  External Dependencies does not mean "you are limited to using these things."  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The "External Dependencies" folder in your project contains a list of headers that the C++ IntelliSense engine has determined are used by your project.

The "External Dependencies" folder in no way impacts how your project is built (you can even disable the folder, under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> "Disable External Dependencies Folder").  It is there for informational purposes.

If you include a C++ header (`<vector>`, for example), then right click your project and select "Rescan Solution," you should see the header file `<vector>` and all of its dependencies appear in the list.   (You probably don't have to use "Rescan Solution," but I'm not 100% sure on what events cause the C++ IntelliSense engine to pick up new header files.)